# Why Urbanairship need GCM keys? How the urbanairship works?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I want push notifications in my app so that i am researching about push notifications, GCM and Urbanairship. While seeing, many people saying that Urbanairship delivery success rate is high. In urbanairship, its asking GCM keys. Why Urbanship need GCM keys? How Urbanairship works?

Answer (score 0):

Urbanairship is talking to GCM on your behalf. If you want Urbanairship to send out your messages to Android devices, you have to prove you have a GCM account.

(For iOS devices you would need an APNS certificate from Apple, and hand that over too.)

Comment: Ok. So urbanairship doesn't use GCM service at back end. right?

Comment: Wrong. It does use it! Read "Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is the transport method that Urban Airship supports for Android notifications" at http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/push-providers/gcm.html